# Dab vs Dac transformer

Tags: transformer, delta

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKb9QM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why might one use a delta-wye transformer with the delta configured in Dab rather than Dac, or vise versa? Will this cause a difference in phase sequence? In Dab, coil A's non-polarity side is connected to coil C's polarity side, and in Dac coil A's non-polarity side is connected to coil B's polarity side, as shown in the schematic.

Comment: What is "Dab" and "Dac"? Add a drawing or schematic so we know what you're talking about. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar, if that helps.

Comment: I have added a schematic, hopefully it properly illustrates what I mean.

Comment: "Will this cause a difference in phase sequence?" // Not in phase sequence, but in phase shift.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: This is not my area of expertise. Your question made me do some research.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFjHms.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) DAB - **D**elta with **A** and **B** on first phase. (b) DAC - **D**elta with **A** and **C** on first phase. Note that the DAB wye phase to phase voltages* lag *the primary whereas the DAC voltages* lead.

> Will this cause a difference in phase sequence?

The phasor diagrams show that the sequence is still red, yellow, blue but that (with anti-clockwise rotation) DAC's secondaries lag the primary by 30° and DAB's lead by 30°. The difference between DAB and DAC is 60°.

Whether all this makes a difference depends on how the secondaries are wired together and if, for example, they are connected to Va, Vb and Vc as they can be on some poly-phase systems. See [30° phase shift](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244697/what-are-the-pros-cons-on-the-30-degree-voltage-phase-shift-between-the-primary) for an example.

Further reading suggests that knowing whether its DAB or DAC is very important for certain fault detection circuits such as that shown in Figure 10 of Basler Electric's [Transformer Protection Application Guide](http://sites.ieee.org/fw-pes/files/2013/01/transfguide.pdf).

[image]

> Incorrect selection of DAB vs. DAC compensation is a common source of trouble during
>   the commissioning stage and, on lightly loaded
>   transformers, can be a source of misoperations
>   seen long after initial startup.
>
> These two methods to connect a delta have very
>   large effects on which phases on the delta side
>   see current during a wye side fault. For example,
>   examine the wye side faults seen in Fig. 10. Note
>   that, for the DAB delta, the wye side A phase to
>   ground fault creates current in the lines A and B
>   on the delta side, but for a DAC delta, the wye
>   side A phase to ground fault creates currents in
>   lines A and C on the delta side.

There is plenty more in the paper that may be of interest.

Further reading: [Powerstar Inc](http://powerstarinc.com/Inrush.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

*There is a major difference in some cases*. Drawing 2 (Dab) has a Va-Vb,Vb-Vc,Vc-Va which maintains the 3-phase relationship needed to drive 3-phase motors. In other words the phases create a 'rotation effect' by maintaining a 120 deg phase shift, so the motor rotates as well.
 For any application where a 3-phase bridge rectifier is used to convert the AC to DC, then either design will work as the phases are simply summed together, creating a 180 HZ ripple which is easily smoothed into a DC voltage. The 'Dab' wiring ensures 3-phase motors will work, else it is a case of "don't care". If the phases are used individually it is also a case of "don't care".