# Wye to delta 3 phase

Tags: power, transformer, three-phase, y-to-delta

Can someone please explain to me the following. For the last part, why did they use the Van to find Vab( secondary line voltage of the delta).

I did it and my magnitude matches the solution but the phase angle doesnt. I used the VAB which is 1732 angle of 0 (reference) and the wye to delta formula which stated VL(secondary delta) = VL(primary wye)/(sqrt3 * A). where A is the transformer ratio [image]. Please explain.

Comment: So what numerically did you get that was different to the above?

Comment: I got Vab = 100 angle of zero. This also contribute to my current being wrong as my current for Ia = 300 angle -50.

Comment: A Y delta transformer introduces a 30 degree phase shift because the reference phase voltage (Y input) is not at zero degrees. Read [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191232/why-does-a-delta-wye-transformer-make-30-degrees-phase-shift). It's for a delta wye transformer but the phase angle occurs in either direction.

Comment: you sire, just made my day! thanks!