# Transforming a Δ source to a Y source

Tags: ac, power-electronics, three-phase

When having Y-Δ or Δ-Y 3 phase circuits, it is more convenient to transform the source configuration into the load configuration to make the circuit easier.

When going from a Δ source with line-line voltage of 400V to a Y source with phase voltage of 400/sqrt(3), we need to subtract -30 degrees from the initial phase of the Δ source, correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYaHB1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: [Very much related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191232/why-does-a-delta-wye-transformer-make-30-degrees-phase-shift/191243#191243).

Comment: @Andyaka So the Δ source is ahead of the Y  source by 30 degrees?

Comment: If you mean when transforming a delta source to a wye source via a transformer then yes.

Comment: im talking about 3 phase source transformation

Comment: You need to probably draw what you mean. However, if you want to compare a straight delta supply with a transformed-to-Y supply you would advance the phase of the delta supply by 30 degrees to keep the transformed Y output in phase with the original delta supply.

Comment: So if we want to compare a Δ supply with a initial phase of 0 degrees then when we transform it to a Y supply we need to subtract 30 degrees.

Comment: Loads on the secondary of the transformers don't care about the phase relation between primary and secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Line voltage leads phase voltage by 30° as per this diagram (taken from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191232/why-does-a-delta-wye-transformer-make-30-degrees-phase-shift/191243#191243)): -

[image]

\$V_{AB}\$ is the line voltage and, \$V_A\$ is its related phase voltage. So, if you wanted a version of \$V_A\$ that is in phase with \$V_{AB}\$, you need to advance it by 30° in time or, subtract 30° from it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried simulating it on the multisim live circuit simulator and these are the results:

[image]

It is clearly shown that when transforming sources we must take into consideration the phase shift between Δ and Y source(the voltage of the resistor with the Δ voltage source is ahead of the voltage of the resistor with the Y source by 30 degrees).