# Why starting current in star-delta starter becomes 1/√3 times that of DOL starter?

Tags: motor, induction-motor, electric-machine

I have seen this statement in a question paper. I was asked to prove it but I can not find the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea is that a smaller voltage is delivered to the motor windings during start up.

The end game is that the motor (or load) is configured as a delta winding formation. In other words, after the load is up and running, each winding receives line voltage.

However, during start-up the windings are put into star formation and each winding will receive 57.7% of the AC voltage.

[image]

When starting the motor (above) KM3 and KM1 activate whilst KM2 is deactivated. You should be able to see that KM1 terminates the motor windings into a star point thus the supply voltage to each winding is only 57.7%.

After a short while KM1 deactivates and KM2 activates. This puts all three motor windings into a delta configuration thus each winding receives 100% line voltage.

Here's a picture that shows (or implies) that math: -

[image]

[Here's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/92678/three-phase-power-supply-what-is-line-to-line-voltage) the SE question where I borrowed the final picture from.

Answer (score 1):

In the time of starting in [star-delta starter](https://learnelectrician.com/star-delta-starter-of-induction-motor/) we first connect the motor winding in star formation. In this case we are delevering only 230V each winding. When voltage is reduced current is also reduced by the ohm's law V=IR,Where R is constant. When motor picks up the speed above the 33% of rated we change the winding connection to the delta by activating delta contactor with the help of ON-delay Timer.

[image: Star-delta starter control diagram]

[image: Star-Delta power diagram]

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen this statement in a question paper. I was asked to prove it but I can not find the logic.

You are right. The question itself is erroneous. Starting current in star would be 1/3 that in delta and not 1/√3.